# Create new column when when values repeat 3 or more times

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a new column (`b`) based on values from a previous column (`a`). Column `a` is binary, consisting of either **0's** or **1's**. If there are three or more **1's** in a row in column `a`, then keep them in column `b`. I'm close to the desired output, but when there are two **1's** in a row, the `ifelse` grabs the second value because it's meeting the first condition.

**Desired Output–Column `b`**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1),
                 b = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1))
df
   a b
1  1 1
2  1 1
3  1 1
4  0 0
5  0 0
6  1 0
7  0 0
8  1 0 #
9  1 0 # 
10 0 0
11 1 1
12 1 1
13 1 1
14 0 0
15 1 0 #
16 1 0 #
17 0 0
18 1 1
19 1 1
20 1 1
21 1 1
```

**Failed Attempt...s**

```
require(dplyr)
df_fail <- df %>% mutate(b=ifelse((lag(df$a) + df$a) > 1 |(df$a + lead(df$a) + lead(df$a,2)) >= 3, df$a,NA))

df_fail
   a b
1  1 1
2  1 1
3  1 1
4  0 0
5  0 0
6  1 0
7  0 0
8  1 0
9  1 1 # should be 0
10 0 0
11 1 1
12 1 1
13 1 1
14 0 0
15 1 0
16 1 1 # should be 0
17 0 0
18 1 1
19 1 1
20 1 1
21 1 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rle` from `base R` to change the elements that have less than 3 repeating 1s to 0

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(df$a), values[values == 1 & lengths <3] <- 0))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

---

Or use `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(a)) %>%
   mutate(b1 = if(n() <3 & all(a == 1)) 0 else a) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-grp)
```

Comment: I actually just swapped your initial answer for my `ifelse` and it worked great. `df_fail <- df %>% mutate(b=inverse.rle(within.list(rle(a), values[values == 1 & lengths <3] <- 0)))`

Comment: @NickDylla   You don't need `df$a` inside `mutate`, it can be just `a`

Comment: Nice catch, forgot to `dplyr`ize it ;)